# view background color in ios

Tags: ios, colors, background

i have add the background color for view.when i change the orientation portrait to Landscape color is collapsed.I attached screen shots.

Portrait:

[image]

Landscape:

[image]

```
CAGradientLayer *color = [back_color blackWhiteGradient];
color.frame = self.back_view.bounds;
[self.back_view.layer insertSublayer:color atIndex:0];
```

Thank you....

Comment: did you use gradient?

Comment: can you show your tried code

Comment: @Kishore  Yes i use gradient.

Comment: @karthik - i update my question with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just add below coding and it work perfectly.

```
     - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
    {
        // resize your layers based on the view’s new bounds
        [[[self.back_view.layer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0] setFrame:self.back_view.bounds];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
{
    // code for landscape orientation      
}
OR

 if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
 {
     // code for Portrait orientation       
 }
```

Change the gradient depend upon the orientation ,then you will get the exact colour,you set the gradient for portrait try like this.

hope this will helps you....

Answer (score 0):

```
CAGradientLayer *color = [back_color blackWhiteGradient];
color.frame = self.back_view.bounds;
[self.back_view.layer insertSublayer:color atIndex:0];
```

Call this code when orientation changes and make instance variable of it when orientation changes also remove the gradient first then re-create the gradient.
this is not working because gradient apply according to its screen size so it not automatically re-draw its surface when orientation change.